# Is it ok to have special domain factory - or something similar - directly in DAL?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

In DDD application, I know that Domain Factory should be the single point of Domain object creation (input from the UI, the results of queries from persistence) - but I'm facing a problem that for very complex queries, we use stored procedures with multiple data sets - so data are translated to structures (classes) highly dependent on persistence implementation, e.g.

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

... processing many record sets

reader.NextResult();
var userRows = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext
               .Translate<UserRow>(reader).ToList();
```

In this case, userRows contains a table of relevant users (only few relevant columns from otherwise very complex table). **And to tehe point** - so far, we use static class `DomainModelHelper` defined in DAL, that in this case, e.g. from `ID` (obtained from the different table in the same query) and `userRows` creates domain object `UserInfo` (that contains basic information about the user), e.g.

```
// here we create aggregate root
...

foreach (var something in somethingRows)
{
    var createdBy = DomainModelHelper.CreateUserInfo(something.CreatedById ?? 0, userRows)
    ...
    // add this domain object to aggregate root
}
```

This can work, but for some reason, this doesn't seem quite right. Is there any other - better - pattern or approach I'm now aware of?

Comment: Your question suffers from the invalid assumption that DDD is somehow a software development technique, or a collection of coding best practices.  It is neither.

Comment: You're surely right, as I see it it might sound like that; but I mentioned DDD just because the application otherwise follows DDD, so I wanted to add relevant context. And I'm obsessed by consistency. And according to Fowler, DomainFactory belongs to the domain layer, hence inconsistency in otherwise nice consistent application :)

Comment: Anyway, any other insight will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Perfect is the enemy of good.  Explain the phrase "this doesn't seem quite right."

Comment: I should read more from Voltair. You described my ultimate problem, btw. It doesn't seem right, because now there are two points, where domain objects come to existence - I believe it should be ok, other layers wouldn't be concerned how the domain model was created, as long as it's correctly returned by repository, but yes, this is why it doesn't seem quite right - two points with the same functionality (factory in the domain layer, helper in the DAL, the only difference is data source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository is responsible for hydrating and de-hydrating your aggregate roots.  Therefore, it is responsible for building the object graph from your aggregate root down to all of its child entities and value objects.  The fact that the code used to do so is separated out into a helper class does not exclude the fact that the repository is still doing its job.

The domain factory is meant for application code that is wanting to create NEW domain objects and defines the requirements for what you need to instantiate a new aggregate root, but is not persistence related.

Think of it like this, when you buy a car, you need money, a license, and insurance.  So, the dealership is like a domain factory.  You can't get a new car until you have those things.  However, if you store your car in your garage, when you go retrieve your car from your garage, you expect it to be in the exact same condition it was in when you put it there.  The repository is like your garage.